How to see inline suggestions from tabnine/codium/copilot and the native quick suggestions widget of the vscode, at the same time in VScode?
I have recently started using an ai autocomplete extension on vscode. But now it is facing conflicts with the already present autocomplete feature.
I want that both inline suggestion from the extension and native quick suggestion widget get shown at the same time. And when I press the tab inline suggestion get accepted and with enter the quick suggestion.
Right now when quick suggestion is there, there is no inline suggestions.
you can take reference from the similar kind of question
VS Code suggestion widget and inline suggestions conflict
I have following in my keybindings.json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit",
    "when": "inlineSuggestionHasIndentationLessThanTabSize && inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorHoverFocused && !editorTabMovesFocus "
}

